# Unable to get the few messages from Queue iBM MQ 7.0

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

Im using IBM MQ 7.0 for getting and putting messages. I was not able to get the all messages from one queue. I was able to get the few messages but few are not able to get. My application is trying to get 5 times and im getting the error as reason code = 2009 and completion code = 2. It is happening very frequently and im not sure why it is happening for only few messsages. If i reprocess those messages again to queue then it is working again. Other queues are working fine on the same server and only two queues are giving this error. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem got fixed after upgrading to 7.0.1.8.

Answer (score 0):

`2009` is "connection broken". You need to look at the completion code and reason code for the five failures (MQGETs of some description) *before* that point.

Once you know that, it will be a much simpler matter to determine your problem. Given the good error codes you generally get from MQ, it will probably be blindingly obvious :-)

If the *first* error you're getting is `2009`, IBM has an article [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21472342) on the most common causes which you may want to look at.

Comment: Here is the error that im getting. Im getting this error frequently but not all time. WebSphereMQ exception (cc=2, rc=2009) while receiving a message from the queue 'TestQueue' at IBM.WMQ.MQBase.throwNewMQException() at IBM.WMQ.MQDestination.Get(MQMessage message, MQGetMessageOptions gmo, Int32 maxMsgSize) at IBM.WMQ.MQDestination.Get(MQMessage message, MQGetMessageOptions gmo)

Comment: @reddy, are you stating that the first reason code you get is 2009? Your original question seemed to indicate you got 2009 _after_ the five attempts.

Comment: sorry - i have edited my question. My application is trying to get the message and it will try for five times. I was getting the same error for five times.

Comment: I found a IBM link which exactly is my problem. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IZ63971   In this link IBM is asking to upgrade but is it possible to fix without upgrade?

Comment: @reddy, no, if there's no data in the 'temp fix' section of the APAR, then the only solution is to install the fixpack.

Answer (score 0):

That fix is only for WMQ Client v7.0.1.0.  Are you using that EXACT version?  Secondly, as per the APAR, "messages larger than about 32000 bytes".  So are your messages larger than 32000 bytes?

RC of 2009 generally means that your channel name is wrong.  Channel names are case sensitive.  e.g. JAVA.CHL is not the same as java.chl nor is it the same as Java.Chl.

If you define a channel via runmqsc as:

```
define channel(java.chl) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) TRPTYPE(TCP)
```

Because you did not use quotes around the name of the channel, MQ will uppercase the channel name (i.e. JAVA.CHL) when it defines it.  Hence, it is best to always uppercase names with MQ.

Comment: my channel table file looks good and no issues with that. Yes im using exact v7.0.1.0 version and my messages are larger